# Nuxt application using Express won't allow POST routes to be hit externally of application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, nuxt.js

**Background**

I have a NUXT application that renders vue templates as you would expect. I have a need to hit some Express routes in the application from external applications client side.

I can hit GET routes from external applications but POST requests fail with a error 404.

**Example**

*Express*

*This works*

```
router.get('/test/get', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: "Global PDF Generator is configured correctly", status: "operational" })
});
```

*This fails with 404*

```
router.post('/test/post', (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: "Global PDF Generator is configured correctly", status: "operational" })
});
```

Inside of the Nuxt application and within any of the vue components I can hit the POST routes like this,

```
fetch('api/v1/pdf', { method: 'POST' }
```

But if we try to do something like this it fails,

```
fetch('localhost:3000/api/v1/pdf', { method: 'POST' }
```

The second example is important because obvioulsy that is how I would have to hit an end point in this application from an outside application.

What I can not figure out is why the GET requests work and do not get a 404 while the POST requests continue to get a 404 from external applications.

**Question**

How can I create an externally accessible Express POST end point in my NUXT application so that it will be directly accessible from an external source?

Comment: Are you using some sort of parser for your post route?

Comment: fetch is going to use a GET unless you add a method parameter -- fetch('localhost:3000/api/v1/pdf', { method: 'POST'})

Comment: Yes of course, I am using POST.

Comment: @EdwinDelRio I am not using anything special. As you can see those 2 test routes in the question are as simple as it gets. I can hit the get externally but not the POST. for example, if I try to hit the POST route in Postman right now it will fail.

Comment: Are you using `http` or `https`? have you tried `fetch('http://localhost:3001/...')`

Comment: @wuno -- you should edit your question to include the fact that you're doing a post on your fetch, because based on what you typed in your question, you aren't.  I just confirmed that Nuxt with Express returns a 404 on a GET to a router.post route.  As you have your question typed out (without the method: POST in the fetch), you're getting exactly what would be expected.  In other words, this fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test', {}) fails with a 404 for me.  And this fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/test', {method:'POST'}) works as fine.

Comment: I updated my question for you so you see POST in the example of a fetch showing the URL difference. @clockwatcher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not as an answer but just so I can format things and demonstrate that something else must be going on.  This minimal example works fine for me.

```
vue init nuxt-community/express-template sample_post
cd sample_post
npm install
```

Modify api/routes/users.js adding a post route:

```
router.post('/test', function(req, res, next) {
   res.json(message: 'hello');
});
```

Start up the service:

```
npm run dev
```

Verify it returns a post from an external request successfully:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:3000/api/test
{"message":"hello"}
```

So something else must be going on somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This is because when the NuxtJs app on production it sees only page `routes` not server `route`. You should use NuxtJs `serverMiddleware`. You can find it [here](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-servermiddleware/) from NuxtJs API

Comment: Answer with serverMiddleware: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292167/4378314