# Is it possible to accept POST request in vuejs (client-side)?

Tags: vue.js

The code below handles GET request and will display the login page:

```
const routes = [
 {
  path: '/',
  name: 'root',
  component: Login
 }
]
```

I can display data using router with GET method in vuejs. Now, I want accept POST requests/methods from external website. Is it possible? If it is, how should I make it, if not possible, is there another alternative solution for this?

Comment: Did you try this? https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-after-navigation

Comment: `POST` requests need to be processed by a server. Your description is vague, but it seems you have a function router (Vue-router?) and server already; perhaps it's a Nuxt instance? In any case, you'd need to implement some "server middleware" to process the POST request and do appropriate logic. If Nuxt, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292167/4378314) should be relevant to you.

Answer (score 3):

No, a client app in a browser cannot accept requests from other websites/services, no matter which HTTP method is going to be used.

If you want for some reason your Vue based application to be accessible remotely then you can consider using [SSR](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html).

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible. Your routes are not even GET requests. You can intercept any request on your own application, but you can't listen for external requests, that's what HTTP servers are for.

Answer (score 0):

### Pass data via the webpage holding the Vue instance

Yes you can with a trick!

What is your first base file that is loading your vuejs ?

is this an html file like **index.html**?

try load your vuejs in a php file like **index.php** and at top of your php file like  write this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    ...
    <script >
        window.postedData = '<?php echo json_encode($_POST)?>';
    </script>
    ...
</head>
```

Now you can use your **postedData** variable every where in your vuejs code

```
mounted() {
    const arr=JSON.parse(postedData)
    console.log(arr)
    ...
 }
```

Comment: To be clear, this is an awkward way (using the window object), should be a last resort and may only be useful to someone who doesn't have full control over how the Vue instance is rendered. In any case, it seems like the original poster is already dealing with what looks like a typical Vue router definition, and if this is the case then their solution will be completely different.