# How to send a request from Nuxt.js client over Nuxt.js server and receive the response back to the client

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I'm developing a Vue.js application which has only frontend (no server) and send a lot of requests to different APIs. The originally quite simple app became more complex. And there are problems with some APIs, because browsers do not accept the responses due to [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). That is why I'm trying to test, if I can migrate the app to Nuxt.js.

My approach is as follows (inspired by this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54292167/3886962)), but I expect, that there is probably a better way to send the requests from the client over the server.

pages/test-page.vue

```
methods: {
  async sendRequest(testData) {
    const response = await axios.post('api', testData)
    // Here can I use the response on the page.
  }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
serverMiddleware: [
  { path: '/api', handler: '~/server-middleware/postRequestHandler.js' }
],
```

server-middleware/postRequestHandler.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

const configs = require('../store/config.js')

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  let body = ''

  req.on('data', (data) => {
    body += data
  })

  req.on('end', async () => {
    if (req.hasOwnProperty('originalUrl') && req.originalUrl === '/api') {
      const parsedBody = JSON.parse(body)

      // Send the request from the server.
      const response = await axios.post(
        configs.state().testUrl,
        body
      )

      req.body = response
    }
    next()
  })
}
```

middleware/test.js (see: [API: The Context](https://nuxtjs.org/api/context/))

```
export default function(context) {
  // Universal keys
  const { store } = context
  // Server-side
  if (process.server) {
    const { req } = context
    store.body = req.body
  }
}
```

pages/api.vue

```
<template>
  {{ body }}
</template>
<script>
export default {
  middleware: 'test',
  computed: {
    body() {
      return this.$store.body
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When the user makes an action on the page "test", which will initiate the method "sendRequest()", then the request "axios.post('api', testData)" will result in a response, which contains the HTML code of the page "api". I can then extract the JSON "body" from the HTML.

I find the final step as suboptimal, but I have no idea, how can I send just the JSON and not the whole page. But I suppose, that there must be a much better way to get the data to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Proxy (see: https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy)
2. API (see: https://medium.com/@johnryancottam/running-nuxt-in-parallel-with-express-ffbd1feef83c)

**Ad 1. Proxy**

The configuration of the proxy can look like this:

*nuxt.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
...
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  proxy: {
    '/proxy/packagist-search/': {
      target: 'https://packagist.org',
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/proxy/packagist-search/': '/search.json?q='
      },
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

The request over proxy can look like this:

```
axios
  .get('/proxy/packagist-search/' + this.search.phpLibrary.searchPhrase)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(
      'Could get the values packagist.org',
      response.data
    )
    }
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log(
      'Could not get the values from packagist.org',
      e
    )
  })
```

**Ad 2. API**

Select *Express* as the project’s server-side framework, when creating the new Nuxt.js app.

*server/index.js*

```
...
app.post('/api/confluence', confluence.send)
app.use(nuxt.render)
...
```

*server/confluence.js* (simplified)

```
const axios = require('axios')
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js')

exports.send = function(req, res) {
  let body = ''
  let page = {}

  req.on('data', (data) => {
    body += data
  })

  req.on('end', async () => {
    const parsedBody = JSON.parse(body)
    try {
      page = await axios.get(
        config.api.confluence.url.api + ...,
        config.api.confluence.auth
      )
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('ERROR: ', e)
    }
  }

  res.json({
    page
  })
}
```

The request over API can look like this:

```
this.$axios
  .post('api/confluence', postData)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log('Wiki response: ', response.data)
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log('Could not update the wiki page. ', e)
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Now with nuxtjs3 :

[nuxtjs3 rc release](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/)

1. you have fetch or useFetch no need to import axios or other libs, what is great, automatic parsing of body, automatic detection of head

[fetching data](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching#data-fetching)

2. you have middleware and server api on same application, you can add headers on queries, hide for example token etc

[server layer](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/concepts/server-engine#api-layer)

a quick example here in vue file i call server api :

```
const { status } = await $fetch.raw( '/api/newsletter', { method: "POST", body: this.form.email } )
    .then( (response) => ({
        status: response.status,
    }) )
    .catch( (error) => ({
        status: error?.response?.status || 500,
    }) );
```

it will call a method on my server, to init the server on root directory i created a folder name server then api, and a file name newsletter.ts (i use typescript)
then in this file :

```
export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
const {REST_API, MAILINGLIST_UNID, MAILINGLIST_TOKEN} = useRuntimeConfig();
const subscriber = await readBody(event);
console.log("url used for rest call" + REST_API);
console.log("token" + MAILINGLIST_TOKEN);
console.log("mailing list unid" + MAILINGLIST_UNID);
let recipientWebDTO = {
    email: subscriber,
    subscriptions: [{
        "mailingListUnid": MAILINGLIST_UNID
    }]
};
const {status} = await $fetch.raw(REST_API, {
    method: "POST",
    body: recipientWebDTO,
    headers: {
        Authorization: MAILINGLIST_TOKEN,
    },
}).then((response) => ({
    status: response.status,
}))
    .catch((error) => ({
        status: error?.response?.status || 500,
    }));
event.res.statusCode = status;
return "";
})
```

What are the benefits ?

- REST_API,MAILING_LIST_UNID, MAILING_LIST_TOKEN are not exposed on
  client and even file newsletter.ts is not available on debug browser.
- You can add log only on server side You event not expose api url to avoid some attacks
- You don't have to create a new backend just to hide some criticals token or datas

then it is up to you to choose middleware route or server api. You don't have to import new libs, h3 is embedded via nitro with nuxtjs3 and fetch with vuejs3

for proxy you have also sendProxy offered by h3 : [sendProxy H3](https://www.jsdocs.io/package/h3#sendProxy)

When you build in dev server and client build in same time(and nothing to implement or configure in config file), and with build to o, just don deploy your project in static way (but i think you can deploy front in static and server in node i don't know)