# using Nuxt for server-side-rendering just for one page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have panel is developed by vuejs and vuetify that uses of v-router for managing routes in client-side, actually I had developed approximately 70% of my panel and in and due to the final change, I have to handle the server post request only to return from the payment page.
I want to use NUXT for SSR, but the problem is that NUXT ignores all my past routes because it does not have these routes itself.
My question is, can NUXT only be used to load just one page after server request to client while my panel work properly in the client-side?
I am new to web programming and I hope I have asked the right question. Anyway, thank for all your helps.

I added nossr.vue in pages directory without index.vue file(This is the only component in this directory and the rest of my vue components are placed in the Components directory).
I use of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289615/how-to-read-post-request-parameters-in-nuxtjs][1] for custom middleware and post request handle class.

Here is postRequestHandle.js:

```
const querystring = require('querystring');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    let body = '';

    req.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log("post request data",data)

        body += data;
    });

    req.on('end', () => {
        req.body = querystring.parse(body) || {};
        console.log("post request handler",req.body)

        next();
    });
};
```

and nuxt.config.js

```
export default {
    devServer: {
        host: 'mypanel.test.net',
        port: 8080,
        disableHostCheck: true,
        hotOnly: true,

    },

    serverMiddleware: [
        { path: '/clickout', handler: './server-middleware/postRequestHandler.js' },

    ],
    layout(context) {
        return 'nossr'
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an extra layouts in Nuxt called `nossr.vue`, make it's first element a `<client-only>` element. On every page except the SSR rendered page you put this:

```js
export default {
  layout: 'nossr'
}
```

For more information regarding layouts in Nuxt, please look at this https://nuxtjs.org/guides/directory-structure/layouts/

Comment: Firstly,thanks a lot for your reply. I edited my question, I added anything that you had suggested but unfortunately I can't see any log that i added in postRequestHandle when I send request from postman . Can you tell me please where I am going wrong?

Comment: @Qazali i'm not really sure what you mean

Comment: Your suggestion made my own routes work but I can not listen to the request coming from the server .I want to listen to http://mypanel.test.net:8080/clickout for rendering new component when I received post request from server.

Comment: Can you show me the code of where you retrieve the data?

Comment: Sure. In postRequestHandle.js that I added to my question I am waiting to server response in the req.on method.

Comment: This HTTP call needs to be server rendered right? WHy don't you do this in asyncData?

Comment: I am new in web development and actually I don't sure that whether I can use of asyncData for waiting for another server send post request to my panel and I could parse request body.

Comment: Alright, try and do some easier things is what I'd recommend, but if you really need to figure it out, you can look here: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/

Comment: Thank you for all your help, my reputation is low and sorry I can not rate your answer.good luck.

Comment: It's no problem, glad I could help!!

Answer (score 3):

You can disable SSR for every page except your particular page by setting `res.spa = true` in the serverMiddleware

```js
export default function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url !== '/clickout') {
    res.spa = true;
  } 
  next();
}
```

See also:
[Nuxt Issue: Per-route ssr](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/1468#issuecomment-324692324)

Comment: Thank you, this saved the day for me. 